# Is there a way to use Github actions secrets that contains another secret?

Tags: github, devops, github-actions, cicd

I want to create a CI/CD using github actions workflow file.
I want to define secrets to be used in the workflow on the github actions settings tab.
Is there a way to include one secret inside another?
For example I have:

```
SECRET1 = test.
SECRET2 = $SECRET1-second.
```

And the value of SECRET2 is supposed to be "test-second".
I know it is possible this way in gitlab.
I want it to be done on the github setting level. It can be done in the workflow file as defining the SECRET2 as ${{secrets.SECRET1}}-second
But that is not the way I'm looking for.
I also tried at the value of the secret use ${{secrets.SECRET1}} and it did not work.
Any way then?

Comment: no, this is not possible